# How to add/open an UPS account while requesting access key in UPS Developer Kit?

Tags: website

I want to create a developer account and get a dummy access key for testing ups shipment in my website. So that I created an account in https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit site. Then I tried to get access key. In that I filled all required fields except add/open a UPS account. Does anyone knows how to add/open a UPS account for developer account to request Access Key ?
I added a screenshot and link for clarification:
[image]
https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/requestaccesskey?loc=en_US